# How to add a border around all elements in the body of a webpage?

Tags: html, css

There is some weird white space showing up on the right side of my website in mobile. I was wondering if there is a CSS trick to add a border to all the html elements within the body of a webpage so that I can figure out which element is extending out and causing the white space on mobile.

Thank you

Comment: `* {border:1px solid redl}`

Comment: You can also inspect element to find the offending element. Post a link and one of us will check it out for you.

Comment: agree with Vector. As the answers below state you can use * {} to select everything on your page but I believe that will significantly affect your page load time. You should find the cause of this and fix it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try this CSS snippet:

```
* { border: 1px solid black; }
```

Every element should now get a border. Beware, this means everything. Hopefuly it'll help you figure out that white space in your app!

Include that CSS snippet before your CSS files so that it can be overwritten - or after, to force it onto every element.

Comment: every element will get a bloody border and that borders will be accounted to the elements widths. `box-sizing: border-box;` would help to temporarily prevent a total mess.

Comment: I personally use box-sizing: border-box on every single element by default for everything anyways.

Answer (score 22):

Try with

```
* { 
  outline: 1px solid red;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}
```

`*` is a global selector, while `outline` will not mess with your elements positions, it'll just add a 1px red outline

Also make sure you use a CSS reset (usually body has by default 8px margin http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html)

You can resize your window, open the debug console and inspect the elements that might create the issue. Take a look at the Style panel and test-edit the styles until you get it fixed. in Chrome's Console you also have the **Emulate** option to test your page for different devices.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Outline is not border. Outline might be better than border, but that would be something to be said in a comment or in a P.S.

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    border-style: 2px 3px solid dashed #3A5FCD;
}
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don’t just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers.